# Off among question

Tags: grammar

> Second worst off among secondary schools were those in Barnsley, where schools get an average of £4,729 per pupil.

I don't know the usage and meaning of that "off" in this sentence. Please some experts explain this clearly.

Comment: The idiom is "worst off".

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/the-worst-off

Comment: Among secondary schools, those in Barnsley were second worst off, ....

Comment: Maybe you just need to say "second lowest," as you're talking about funds available per pupil.

Answer (score 1):

To be "badly off" is an idiomatic expression that means "not doing well" or "not having enough money." In this case "worse" is the comparative form, so the sentence means that the schools in Barnsley are second to last in the money they get.

Comment: No resource cited, no link to a resource,... Not a good answer.

Comment: Frankly, does this merit a resource? Maybe this should be in ELL.

Comment: This is a well known enough it should not need a cite. +1